Expectation of max of geometric r.v.
Let $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. geometric random variables such that $X_i \sim \text{Geom}(1/2)$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=1$. I want to show that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}(X_i - 1)\right)^2\right] = 0.$$
I believe this should be true since

if the maximum is obtained for some finite $m$, then the above statement is clearly true as the expectation would be finite;

if the maximum is obtained for $m = \mathcal{O}(n)$ and $n$ is large enough, then the (rescaled) sum behaves like a normal random variable, i.e. $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(X_i - 1) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2),$$ and so $$\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}(X_i - 1)\right)^2\right] \sim n \,\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} Y_m^2\right] \sim n\log(n),$$ where $Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$, which means that the limit is also zero in this case.


I don't know, however, how to make it rigorous. I would appreciate any suggestions!

By Doob's maximal inequality,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}(X_i - 1)\right)^2\right] \leqslant 2\mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - 1)\right)^2\right] 
$$
and using again independence,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - 1)\right)^2\right]=
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[(X_i - 1)\ ^2\right].  
$$
Since the random variables $X_i$ have the same distribution, we get
$$
\frac 1{n^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}(X_i - 1)\right)^2\right] \leqslant \frac 2n\mathbb E\left[(X_1-1)^2\right].$$

Incomplete proof:
$$\mathbb{E}X=\int P(X>x) dx$$
so
$$\mathbb{E}\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} S_m
=\int_0^\infty P\left( \max_{1 \leq m \leq n} S_m > x \right) dx$$
Then we can split up the max using that
$$P\left( \max_{1 \leq m \leq n} S_m > x \right) \le \sum_{m=1}^n P\left( S_m > x \right)$$
but also using
$$P\left( \max_{1 \leq m \leq n} S_m > x \right) \le 1$$
to make sure our bound is tight enough, ending up with
$$\le \int_0^\infty \min\left(\sum_{m=1}^n P\left( S_m > x \right),1\right) dx$$
$$= \int_0^{\alpha_n} 1 dx +
\int_{\alpha_n}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^n P\left( S_m > x \right) dx$$
$$= \alpha_n +\sum_{m=1}^n \int_{\alpha_n}^\infty P\left( S_m > x \right) dx$$
Where we can pick any $\alpha_n$. So we want to show that for
$$S_m=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}Y_i\right)^2$$
this expression is in $o(n^2)$. There are many approaches to this, I'm sure, but none look particularly neat, so I'm going to make a claim and hope someone else can fill in the details: for $m'>m$
$$P\left( S_{m'} > x \right) \ge P\left( S_m > x \right)$$
so we can get
$$\mathbb{E}\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} S_m \le \alpha_n +n \int_{\alpha_n}^\infty P\left( S_n > x \right) dx$$
Now, knowing that $S_n$ should grow like $n$, and converge in distribution to the square of a normal distribution we can fix $\alpha_n=\alpha n$ and make the judicious substitution $x=n z^2$:
$$= n\alpha +2n^2 \int_{\alpha}^\infty zP\left( S_n > n z^2 \right) dz$$
and by the CLT $P\left( \sqrt{S_n} > \sqrt{n} z \right)$ converges uniformly to $2\Phi(-\frac{z}{\sigma})$. Hence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2 \int_{\alpha}^\infty zP\left( S_n > n z^2 \right) dz
= 2 \int_{\alpha}^\infty z\Phi(-\frac{z}{\sigma}) dz$$
$$lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} S_m \le
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\alpha +2 \int_{\alpha}^\infty z\Phi(-\frac{z}{\sigma}) dz$$
$$=2 \int_{\alpha}^\infty z\Phi(-\frac{z}{\sigma}) dz$$
This is just a constant depending on $\alpha$,and it holds for any choice of $\alpha$ so we can make the constant arbitrarily small, proving the limit must converge to $0$.

The assumption I made clearly comes out in the limit, but showing this would be messy and I don't want to try to restructure my answer again
